# exclude parents from the_terms

Tags: categories, terms

I'm using this function to get the categories linked to the post:

```
the_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio-type', '<p><b>'.__('Categories:','om_theme').'</b> ', ', ', '</p>');
```

the result is this:

> Categories: 16 Max, Capacity

The category **Capacity** is parent of **16 Max** category.  I'm looking to exclude parents so the result would be:

> Categories: 16 Max

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) instead and exclude any terms where parent value is `0`, which means it is a top-level term.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio-type' );
if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
        if( 0 != $term->parent )
            $output[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) .'">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
    if( count( $output ) )
        echo '<p><b>' . __('Categories:','om_theme') . '</b> ' . join( ", ", $output ) . '</p>';
}
```